# error: has no member named ‘current_date’

Tags: c++

So I have this warehouse class:

warehouse.h:

```
#ifndef WAREHOUSE_H
#define WAREHOUSE_H
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include "dates.h"

namespace a4
{
 class warehouse
 {
    public:
        warehouse(std::string name, std::string start_date);

    private:
        std::string name;
        std::string busiest_day;
        int most_transactions;
        std::map<std::string, a4::food> items;
        dates current_date;
        void next_day();
 };
}
 #endif
```

warehouse.cc:

```
#include "warehouse.h"
#include "dates.h"
namespace a4
{
 //constructor
 warehouse::warehouse(std::string name, std::string start_date)
 {
     this->current_date = new dates(start_date);
 }
 void warehouse::next_day()
 {
     this->current_date.next_day();
 }
}
```

And the compiler error im getting is:

```
warehouse.cc: In constructor ‘a4::warehouse::warehouse(std::string, std::string)’:
warehouse.cc:8: error: ‘class a4::warehouse’ has no member named ‘current_date’
warehouse.cc: In member function ‘void a4::warehouse::next_day()’:
warehouse.cc:12: error: ‘class a4::warehouse’ has no member named ‘current_date’
```

Any idea why its not recognizing `current_date` as a member? It's probably pretty simple but I'm only a few weeks into learning c++.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible. You should be getting an error about conversion from `dates*` to `dates` (because you're using `new` when you should not), instead.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit ah yes i threw the `new` in there hoping it might fix it, it wasnt there before, i forgot to take it out. Stil throws the error either way.

Comment: Make sure "dates" is in the same namespace etc.

Comment: @Deekor: Programming by guessing does not work.

Comment: Remove as much code as you can and see if you still have the problem. There's something you're not showing us and that's where the problem is.

Comment: If your learning C++, where did you learn to use `this->`?  I just reference the data members directly.

Comment: You're not storing the warehouse name anywhere.  Get rid of the parameter in the constructor.

Comment: @thomasmatthews at the university I attend.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Some style guides recommend it. My own stance varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possibility I can see is that this is *not* what your header looks like. Ensure that you've been editing the correct file in the correct directory.

When you've fixed that, you'll find that your next error is "cannot convert `dates*` to `date`". This is because you're using `new` where you should not be.

Comment: So this is a partner assignment and we were using a dropbox folder to save everything. Apparently it updates slowly or something because the changes in my h file weren't being reflected. Once I moved it to a local folder and ran the compiler the error went away.

Comment: Now for some reason it thinks start_date isnt a string. `warehouse.cc:6: error: no matching function for call to a4::dates::dates()
dates.h:10: note: candidates are: a4::dates::dates(std::string)`

Comment: @Deekor: No, that's because you didn't initialise the member `current_date`, which has no default constructor. No, assigning to it in the constructor body is not sufficient - you have to _initialise_ it using the _member initializer list_. Consult your book for further details. Also, it's time to move this to a chatroom or discussion forum.

Comment: @Deekor: I didn't really mean a chatroom for just you and me. I am doing other things. My point is that extended conversations about debugging your issues one at a time isn't really on-topic on a Q&A. You should just spend some time reading. :)